# jQuery variable content undefined yet not undefined

Tags: jquery, debugging, console

I tend to debug by using `alert()`. When I do:

```
var $checkedbox = $("[type='radio']").val();
alert($checkedbox);
```

It pops up and displays the value correctly. Yet in the console when I type in the variable name I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $checkedbox is not defined(…)

Comment: The variable is probably either deleted after the log or defined in an inner scope. Without enough code to reproduce, there's no way to guess your bug. Please use the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button of your question edition toolbar.

Comment: You should really use `console.log()` to debug instead of `alert` as it avoids issues caused by coerced data types.

Comment: Try `window.$checkedbox`......

Comment: Are you testing in jsfiddle? If so, don't forget to choose the correct frame in the console, then what you describe works fine: http://i.imgur.com/vo1KxGt.png

Comment: This is not global variable. you have to add debug pointer for getting the actual result. if You do  not add any debug pointer after 'var $checkedbox = $("[type='radio']").val(); 'line , when method call is finished you can not get the $checkedbox from console.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I wasn't aware of that. console.log also return the correct value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkedbox as a **global variable**.

```
window.$checkedbox = $("[type='radio']").val();
```